# I want to close login form completely and to show main control panel..?

Tags: c#

```
private void btn_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ManageMent.login_check(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text);

    if (ManageMent.Login_Check!=false)
    {
        Control_Center control_panel = new Control_Center();

        control_panel.Show();

        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

im using these codes these codes behind my login button, but this leave the main login form hidden somewhere and when i m closing the control panel it ix still running behind, i want to close it immediately when the authentication is successful.. i tried this.Close(); but it restrict the control panel to open

Comment: What does "it restrict the control panel to open" mean?

Comment: Does the form referenced by `this` have the `IsMdiContainer` property set to `true`?

Comment: mean it closes the control_panel form also along with login form

Comment: no i didnot use IsMdiContainer.. i dont know how to use thix

Comment: is this Form a MDI type of user interface..? if not why are you not storing the user credentials in a parent form, then close the child form upon success? king of hard to tell what you are doing based on just one method..

Comment: @ DJ kraze no thix ix not a MDI type user interface.. i jux want to close my login form completely and show main control panel

Answer (score 0):

the are some more options that you have ....

Actually i think your Login Form Runs as main thread , so closing it will not make you go with another form within that, i mean  main thread  , so trick is to go with simple threading ....

```
if (ManageMent.Login_Check!=false)
    {
            new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(()=>{
                Application.Run(new Control_Center());
            })).Start();

            this.Dispose();
}
```

if you only want to close all form(s) at last , i mean just kidding , then

```
    if (ManageMent.Login_Check!=false)
        {
          this.Hide();
          Control_Center control_panel = new Control_Center();
          control_panel.ShowDialog(this);
          this.Close();
        }
```

Comment: thanx thix ix a great idea..!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create  your application with `Control_Center`

```
Application.Run(new Control_Center());
```

before your control_center form is shown, you should [create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx) a LoginForm. For example you can do when the form is loaded.

```
public partial class Control_Center: Form
{
    public Control_Center()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Control_Center_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();
        var authorizationResult = loginForm .ShowDialog();
        if (authorizationResult  != System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```